# Refresh page after SQL update is finished on current index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that contains a gridview. I have placed a linkbutton at the end of the gridview, when pressed it calls an API and updates my SQL table with the data from the API call. It performs the response.write and appears to refresh the page, but the updates don't show up once it's finished. I have to go forward 1 page and back to the original page for the updates to show up. How can I achieve this?

I have tried using gridview.Save() after the responose.write.
Also tried Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); but it refreshes to pageindex 1.

```
    try {
    connect.Open();                               
    UpdateExistingNote.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Write("Message to user");
    GridView.Save();
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with updating just text in a text box. I fixed the issue by removing the element from the page and then adding the element with the new value again. I did this through javascript. My textbox was dynamically created though.

Comment: Don't do Response.Write.  That writes content to the response, but you have no control over where that content ends up in your DOM. If you want to update.

Comment: @mason I wasn't aware of that, What should I use to put text at the top of the screen to notify the user what happened?

Comment: @kristech thank you, I've noticed I can click inside of a textbox and press enter and the page updates on the current index. Just looking for a way to do the same thing on the backend.  Would you mind posting the script so I can test it?  Thank you

Comment: If you want control over where content ends up, then you should create a label or some other place holder, then set the value (.Text) of that label from your code behind. Of course, I don't recommend any of this. Is this a new project you're working on it for? Why are you doing it in Web Forms? Web Forms [is dead](http://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/stop-using-aspnet-webforms).

Comment: @mason I'm a new hire, this is a website they've had for years. Added some functionality before I start the task of making a newer version (MVC)

Comment: @user608293 My condolences, but at least it sounds like they're aware it needs to be updated to a better framework. What data comes back from the API call? Is it just another row of data? Perhaps you could add that to the table without needing to refresh the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP, here is how i handled the textbox refresh:

Dynamically create textbox:

```
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = "tbNewExpireDate";
                    tb.Text = dt.Rows[j][k].ToString();
                    tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Date;
                    tb.EnableViewState = false;

                    hdOldExpireDate.Value = dt.Rows[j][k].ToString();

                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.OnClientClick += "return VerifyExpireDateSave()";
                    btn.Click += btnSaveExpireDate_Click;
                    btn.Text = "Save";

                    Panel pnl1 = new Panel();
                    pnl1.ID = "pnlExpiration";

                    pnl1.Controls.Add(tb);
                    pnl1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Then add panel to a control.

Javascript to remove the element:

```
   function VerifyExpireDateSave() {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this product key expiration date?");
        document.getElementById('hdNewExpireDate').value = document.getElementById('tbNewExpireDate').value;

        var pnl = document.getElementById('pnlExpiration');
        var tb = document.getElementById('tbNewExpireDate');
        pnl.removeChild(tb);

        return answer;
    }
```

All controls are created in post back so once the javascript function returns true, the post back happens after removing the child element from the panel. This made it so after the post back, the new value was in the textbox. Also, this textbox happened to be a date textbox and the functionality in my program was to update the expiration date of a product key. And the problem i was having was that the old date was showing on reload. The script is what made the correct date show after post back.